# ¿Como guardar multiples imagenes con SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

tengo este problema.

Estoy intentando crear un filtro de imágenes y exponiéndolas en Picturebox's para que el usuario pueda verlas antes de guardarlas, esto funciona correctamente.

El problema reside en que al momento de guardarlas no se como hacer que todas se guarden al mismo tiempo y no una por una.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog guardar = new SaveFileDialog();
        guardar.Title = "Guardar imagenes...";
        guardar.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        guardar.Filter = "JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG (*.png*)|*.png*|BMP (*.bmp)|*.bmp";

        if (guardar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox2.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox3.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox4.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox5.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox6.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox7.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox8.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox9.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox10.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox11.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox12.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox13.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox14.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox15.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox16.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox17.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox18.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
            pictureBox19.Image.Save(guardar.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se especifico ninguna ruta");
        }
```

Este es mi código para guardar las imágenes.

Mi idea era seleccionar una ruta especifica y después guardarlas todas con un nombre de incremento llámese (Imagen1, Imagen2, Imagen3, Imagen4, y así hasta el 19) pero no se como hacerlo.

Ese código solo me guarda la ultima imagen (pictureBox19).

Comment: Podrías crear un clase que se llame por ejemplo Imagen y en tu aplicación principal inicializar una variable como lista List<Imagen>Imagenes, entonces cada vez que el usuario agregue una imagen la vas agregando a la lista, después cuando el usuario presione el botón de guardar, recorres la lista y vas guardando la imagen e incrementando otra variable para darle el número.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con este código puedes refactorizar mejor el tuyo, y asi salvas diferentes fotos con un nombre usandolo como patrón en el mismo directorio que elijas con el SaveFileDialog component. ;P

```
//Añade System.IO; al comienzo de tu archivo

if (guardar.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Cantidad de imagenes
    int cantidadImagenes = 19;
    //Nombre con el cual se llamaran por defecto todas las fotos
    String nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(guardar.FileName);
    //Ubicación donde vas a guardar el archivo
    string directorio = Path.GetDirectoryName(guardar.FileName);
    //Extensión del archivo de foto puedes variarlo por png, jpg, etc
    String extension = Path.GetExtension(guardar.FileName);
    //Recorro n veces para salvar todas las fotos
    for(var i=1;i<cantidadImagenes;i++) {
        //Obtengo el pictureBox basado en su nombre dentro del formulario
        PictureBox imagen = (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find("PictureBox"+i.ToString(), true).First();
        //Se conforma el nombre del archivo para ser salvado por cada foto
        imagen.Image.Save(directorio+"\\"+nombreArchivo+i.ToString()+extension);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se especifico ninguna ruta");
}
```

Comment: Cabe destacar que la cantidad de imagenes varia segun tu implementación y esta estrechamente vinculado a como se llaman tus PictureBox, fijate que en el for yo hago un "PictureBox"+i.ToString()

Comment: Muchas gracias, aunque ahora surge otro problema
No se guarda donde el usuario especifica, sino que se guarda en la carpeta /bin/debug de mi programa en lugar de la ruta que yo le solicito. 

No encuentro que es lo que pueda decirle al programa que se guarde en esa dirección específicamente.

Comment: **Edite la respuesta**, me faltó obtener el directorio que elijes en el cuadro de dialogo de salvar y en esa dirección salvar el archivo de imagen cuando se conforme el nuevo nombre, ya que nombreArchivo solo almacenaba si tu ruta era C:\mi_directorio\archivo1.png solo **archivo1** por tanto al no tener una ruta asociada automaticamente lo salva en el directorio de salida de tu proyecto es decir **Debug**

Comment: Si con este cambio se soluciona aceptala como respuesta correcta y una buena puntuación no estaria nada mal ;P jeje